# Error in ScriptResource: cant read property open of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

while try to open my asp.net web form i get this error in console so i cant open my "cant read property open of undefined " below is the snipet of my console ScriptResource document. error comes on last line "return b.open(a,c);" . interesting thing is i have defined the radwindow manager in my page behind as follow

```
   <telerik:RadWindowManager EnableShadow="false" ID="RadWindowManager1" DestroyOnClose="true"
    Opacity="100" runat="server" Width="1000" Style="z-index: 31000" Height="500"
    OnClientClose="RadWinClose" Behaviors="Close, Move,Reload,Resize" ReloadOnShow="true">
   </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

**ScriptResource in console**

```
Type.registerNamespace("Telerik.Web.UI");
Type.registerNamespace("Telerik.Web.UI.WindowManager");
$telerik.toWindowManager=function(a){return a;
};
$telerik.findWindowManager=$find;
function GetRadWindowManager(){return Telerik.Web.UI.WindowManager.Manager;
}window.radalert=function(e,c,d,a){var b=GetRadWindowManager();
return b.radalert(e,c,d,a);
};
window.radconfirm=function(f,e,d,c,b,g){var a=GetRadWindowManager();
return a.radconfirm(f,e,d,c,b,g);
};
window.radprompt=function(g,f,d,c,b,h,e){var a=GetRadWindowManager();
return a.radprompt(g,f,d,c,b,h,e);
};
window.radopen=function(a,c){var b=GetRadWindowManager();
return b.open(a,c);
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you open your RadWindows? You must ensure that the call to radopen() or wndManagerInstance.open() that you have is executed after the Sys.Application.Load event.